# keysize for Release.gpg?

Tags: debian, gpg

What is the required keysize for generating Debian Release.gpg files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there is a specific key size required.  It's just a detached cleartext GPG signature.  If you describe in more detail the problem you're having, perhaps someone could be of more assistance.

Comment: I am not having a specific... at least not yet. I am in the process of signing my Debian repos and I need to generate some gpg keys.

Comment: I would go with "whatever you feel comfortable with, from a standard cryptographic key length / risk analysis".